# Is using "were" or "are" better in the conversation

Tags: grammaticality, subordinate-clauses, backshifting

May I know which of the following two sentences is grammatical?

> 1. From what I’ve described which aspects would you say **were** the “must haves”?
> 2. From what I’ve described which aspects would you say **are** the “must haves”?

Comment: Is it past tense or present tense? Are the "Must haves" **still** the "must haves" or **were** they the "must haves" in 1960 but aren't any more?

Comment: Both versions are grammatical. As to which one might be more preferable, it would probably depend on the context and on the speaker. Version #2 might be restricted to a present time of "must have" (or maybe not). It seems that version #1 can be used wherever version #2 can be used; also version #1 can be used for a past time of "must have" (if there is such a thing).

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.  If you think some things were essential or indispensable in the past and no longer so in the present, you should use "were must-haves".  If you think that they are so in the present, you should use "are must-haves".